# Python 3 on atom on Mac

Tags: macos, python-3.x, atom-editor

I would like to run my Python 3 on my Mac, but it shows me 2.7 only.

[image: Showing my python3 path]

[image: Error]

Comment: That's a simple case of wrong indentation in your config. If you work with multiple Python versions, I can recommend the [build-python](https://atom.io/packages/build-python) (obviously, I'm biased)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You did not set up Atom Runner for Python 3

In your `config.cson`, you are pointing the `exception-reporting` package to your Python 3 binary, but your error is that Atom Runner cannot find it. You need to tell Atom Runner where Python 3 lives.

```coffee
'runner':
  'scopes':
    'python': '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3'
```

See the [Atom Runner](https://atom.io/packages/atom-runner) listing in the package directory for more.